# how block docker container port with iptables?

Tags: docker, iptables

I use docker service to setup a container network. and I just open a port 7035 for a target ip and expose it to the host.
when i check the iptables with 'iptables -nvL'
I saw the FORWARD chain:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:7053
1680K  119M DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1680K  119M DOCKER     all  --  *      br-287ce7f19804  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1680K  119M ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-287ce7f19804  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

and the DOCKER chain:

```
Chain DOCKER (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-287ce7f19804 br-287ce7f19804  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:7053
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-287ce7f19804 br-287ce7f19804  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:7051
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-287ce7f19804 br-287ce7f19804  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:2181
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-287ce7f19804 br-287ce7f19804  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.4           tcp dpt:7053
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-287ce7f19804 br-287ce7f19804  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.4           tcp dpt:7051
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-287ce7f19804 br-287ce7f19804  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.6           tcp dpt:7053
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-287ce7f19804 br-287ce7f19804  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.6
```

AndI want to block the container 172.18.0.2, and it's port 7053. so I use the `sudo iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.18.0.2 --dport 7053 -j DROP`.

But, It doesn't work. 
So, what should I do to block the target ip and port?

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
iptables -I DOCKER 1 -p tcp --dport 7053 -j DROP
```

This will insert the DROP rule before all the other rules in the DOCKER chain.

The following is a useful commands well:

```
iptables --list DOCKER -n --line
```

As well, if you add `-v` (verbose) you get more detail

By now, you probably have your answer, but it may help others.

Comment: docker iptables rules should be added to the DOCKER-USER chain instead of the DOCKER chain

Comment: Just like the user before said - source: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host