# Docker opened up ports to public. How do I close them?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Surprisingly running docker-compose made some ports open up. I only want to have 80, 22, and 443 being open. How do I achieve that? How do I disable docker being able to open them up? That really feels like a huge security problem.

Comment: Running `docker-compose` displayed only the usage for me. What exactly have you run with what configuration? How did you check the ports are open? Which ports exactly are open?

Comment: @KamilCuk I ran `docker-compose up -d` to start all containers. The ones are open where I did `ports: - "1234:80"`, and it opened up 1234 to public.

Comment: Then please post the configuration of these "all containers". Ie. show docker-compose.yml . `it opened up 1234 to public` this is exactly what ports does

Comment: @KamilCuk I want it not be open to public but just to the local machine.

Answer (score 5):

I'll answer the question that you did not ask and that you actually want to know, in the hopes it will help future readers, mostly because I bumped on the issue myself.

> How to do it safe and properly?

I am assuming the default `--iptables=true` docker configuration.

The default `--ip` when binding a container port is `0.0.0.0` ie. all interfaces. So the container binds to all interfaces, ie. the port `1234` is redirected to port `80` from all incoming interfaces. Because the `DOCKER` chain is added in iptables `nat` table in `PREROUTING` chain, it is redirected usually before anything else normal firewalls insert in `filter` table.

To be safe, modify `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and specify the default `ip` the containers will bind to when redirecting ports:

```
{
    "ip": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

or add the command line option `--ip=127.0.0.1` to your docker instance. That way `ports` when not specified will only insert redirections for localhost.

This may be not enough, as iptables rules can be strange - so knowing your `iptables` rules and modyfing them if needed is advisable. Alternatively you can add some filtering rule to `DOCKER_USER` chain in `filter` table to specifically filter the traffic.

And for instances that you *really* want to expose to outside world, explicitly set `0.0.0.0` (or the ip number of external interface):

```
ports:
- 0.0.0.0:1234:80    # global
- 127.0.0.1:1235:80  # local only
- 1236:80            # whatever defaults is set in docker.json, usually 0.0.0.0
```

> How do I close them?

Stop `docker` service. Stop containers. Remove the rules from iptables. Shutdown your pc. Remove network connection from you pc.

> I only want to have 80, 22, and 443 being open. How do I achieve that?

So redirect only those ports and nothing else.

> How do I disable docker being able to open them up?

Disable iptables support in docker - pass `--iptables=false` to `dockerd` or modify `/etc/docker/daemon.json` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed to resolve the same issue in my linode server. Those are the steps that helped me to secure the server:

1. Disable IPTables for docker

```bash
echo "DOCKER_OPTS=\"--iptables=false\"" >>  /etc/default/docker

# add "iptables": false to /etc/docker/daemon.json
# if you don't have this file, you can run:
echo -e "{\n\"iptables\": false\n}\n" > /etc/docker/daemon.json

# restart docker
service docker restart
```

You should not have docker rules in iptables at this point.

2. Block entire income traffic except ports that are needed. I use `ufw` for it.
3. Create nginx proxy if you need to forward 80 to the docker container port.

Answer (score 1):

Doing:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s 127.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

solved this for me.

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/be-careful-docker-might-be-exposing-ports-world

Comment: setting this iptables rule as the first one in the chain might work better. check this on how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/53843777/9618184